# My K8S node doesn't have podCIDR in node's configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I deployed K8S cluster on AWS EKS (nodegroup) with 3 nodes. I'd like to see the pod CIDR for each node but this command returns empty: `$ kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.podCIDR}'`. Why doesn't it have CIDR in the configuration?

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                                            STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
ip-10-0-1-193.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   94d   v1.21.5-eks-bc4871b
ip-10-0-2-66.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal    Ready    <none>   22m   v1.21.5-eks-bc4871b
ip-10-0-2-96.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal    Ready    <none>   24m   v1.21.5-eks-bc4871b
```

Below is one of the node info.

```
$ kubectl describe node ip-10-0-1-193.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal

Name:               ip-10-0-1-193.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t3.large
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType=ON_DEMAND
                    eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup=elk
                    eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup-image=ami-00c56588b2d911d26
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=ap-southeast-2
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-southeast-2a
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-1-193.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t3.large
                    topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone=ap-southeast-2a
                    topology.kubernetes.io/region=ap-southeast-2
                    topology.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-southeast-2a
Annotations:        csi.volume.kubernetes.io/nodeid: {"ebs.csi.aws.com":"i-0da5d02f6c203fe6b"}
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Fri, 19 Nov 2021 16:04:37 +1100
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  ip-10-0-1-193.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Mon, 21 Feb 2022 20:39:23 +1100
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Mon, 21 Feb 2022 20:37:46 +1100   Fri, 26 Nov 2021 15:42:06 +1100   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Mon, 21 Feb 2022 20:37:46 +1100   Fri, 26 Nov 2021 15:42:06 +1100   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Mon, 21 Feb 2022 20:37:46 +1100   Fri, 26 Nov 2021 15:42:06 +1100   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Mon, 21 Feb 2022 20:37:46 +1100   Fri, 26 Nov 2021 15:42:06 +1100   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:   10.0.1.193
  Hostname:     ip-10-0-1-193.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
  InternalDNS:  ip-10-0-1-193.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
Capacity:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
  cpu:                         2
  ephemeral-storage:           20959212Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:               0
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      8047100Ki
  pods:                        35
Allocatable:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
  cpu:                         1930m
  ephemeral-storage:           18242267924
  hugepages-1Gi:               0
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      7289340Ki
  pods:                        35
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 ec29e60ae2a5ed86515b0b6e7fe39341
  System UUID:                ec29e60a-e2a5-ed86-515b-0b6e7fe39341
  Boot ID:                    f75bc84f-fbd5-4414-87c8-669a8b4e3c62
  Kernel Version:             5.4.149-73.259.amzn2.x86_64
  OS Image:                   Amazon Linux 2
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://20.10.7
  Kubelet Version:            v1.21.5-eks-bc4871b
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.21.5-eks-bc4871b
ProviderID:                   aws:///ap-southeast-2a/i-0da5d02f6c203fe6b
Non-terminated Pods:          (15 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                            CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                            ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  cert-manager                cert-manager-68ff46b886-ndnm8                   0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         89d
  cert-manager                cert-manager-cainjector-7cdbb9c945-bzfx2        0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         89d
  cert-manager                cert-manager-webhook-58d45d56b8-2mr76           0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         89d
  default                     elk-es-node-1                                   1 (51%)       100m (5%)   4Gi (57%)        50Mi (0%)      32m
  default                     my-nginx-5b56ccd65f-sndqv                       0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         18m
  elastic-system              elastic-operator-0                              100m (5%)     1 (51%)     150Mi (2%)       512Mi (7%)     89d
  kube-system                 aws-load-balancer-controller-9c59c86d8-86ld2    100m (5%)     200m (10%)  200Mi (2%)       500Mi (7%)     89d
  kube-system                 aws-node-mhqp6                                  10m (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         94d
  kube-system                 cluster-autoscaler-76fd4db4c-j59vm              100m (5%)     100m (5%)   600Mi (8%)       600Mi (8%)     89d
  kube-system                 coredns-68f7974869-2x4qc                        100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (2%)     89d
  kube-system                 coredns-68f7974869-wfhzq                        100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (2%)     89d
  kube-system                 ebs-csi-controller-7584b68c57-ksvkc             0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         89d
  kube-system                 ebs-csi-controller-7584b68c57-rkbq4             0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         89d
  kube-system                 ebs-csi-node-nxfkz                              0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         94d
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-zcqg4                                100m (5%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         94d
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                    Requests      Limits
  --------                    --------      ------
  cpu                         1610m (83%)   1400m (72%)
  memory                      5186Mi (72%)  2002Mi (28%)
  ephemeral-storage           0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi               0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi               0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs  0             0
Events:                       <none>
```

Answer (score 1):

From kubelet let documentation I can see that it is only being used for standalone configuration
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kubelet-config.v1beta1/

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).